# Removing the specific object from array in mongoose and update it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi i am new in mongoose and mongodb. I want to remove specific object from the Array in my document and return the updated document. I have tried a lot but it always return null. Here is my document structure.

```
{
    "role": "Student",
    "skills": [
        "html",
        "css",
        "js"
    ],
    "_id": "5ef583198e9b23cc8c606c10",
    "user": "5ee5c9ef26333935647e54bc",
    "__v": 24,
    "status": "Intern",
    "education": [],
    "internships": [
        {
            "current": false,
            "_id": "5ef894d48f601512340f25b5",
            "title": "Web",
            "company": "asdfadfd",
            "from": "2010-02-04T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "current": false,
            "_id": "5ef894f31dc9413bf89c44d8",
            "title": "Django",
            "company": "example",
            "from": "2010-02-04T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my updating function

```
exports.deleteStudentInternship = async (req, res, next) => {
    const deleteInternship = await Student.findOneAndUpdate(
        { $and: [{ user: req.user.id }, { 'internships': { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.intern_id } } }] },
        { '$pull': { 'internships': { _id: req.params.intern_id } } },
        {
            new: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
        },
        function (error) {
            if (error) return validationError(404, { internship: 'Internship id not exist' }, next)
        }
    );

    if (!deleteInternship) {
        return validationError(404, { internship: 'Internship id not exist' }, next)
    }
    res.status(200).json(deleteInternship);
}
```

Comment: Does your document got updated?

Comment: Yes document updated successfully  but it return null after the execution i want that updated document

Comment: Can you try removing the `function (error) {}` callback? You are using a callback alongside `async/await` That might cause unexpected behaviours

Comment: Yes i have tried it.

Comment: And `deleteInternship ` is still `null` ?

Comment: yes if i replace this```  $and: [{ user: req.user.id }, { 'internships': { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.intern_id } } }]```  with ```user:req.user.id``` it give the updated document but there is a small bug, if  i again hit with the previous id it can't show me error that  "Invalid id"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216834/discussion-between-thammada-ts-and-janardan-prajapati).

Answer (score 0):

Please change the pull part I mean

`{ '$pull': { 'internships': { _id: req.params.intern_id } } }`

to this and try:

`{ '$pull': { 'internships': req.params.intern_id } }`